# Converting int Array to a string and displaying it in a textarea

Tags: java, arrays

Hey I just started programming and I need help with converting/displaying my array in the `TextArea`. The code below is part of my array class. `output.setText(array[i]);` gives me and error saying "needs `String`, found int". I'm not sure how to convert it and display the list of random numbers that are inside the array.

```
public void setArray(int x){
    for(int i = 0; i > array.length; i++){
        array[i] = x;
    }
}
public void fillArray(){
    int arrayNumbers = randomNumber.nextInt(100)+1;
    for(int i= 0; i > array.length ; i++){
        array[i] = arrayNumbers;
        output.setText(array[i]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all `setText` will replace the content of the text area with the text you supply, you probably should be using `append`

You could use...

```
output.append(String.valueOf(array[i]));
```

Or

```
output.append(Integer.toString(array[i]));
```

To convert the `int` value to `String`

You could also use a `StringBuilder` to build up a `String` value first, for example...

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(array.length);
for(int i= 0; i < array.length ; i++){
    array[i] = arrayNumbers;
    sb.append(array[i]);
}
output.setText(sb.toString());
```

Also, you code generally doesn't make sense...

For example...

```
for(int i= 0; i > array.length ; i++){
```

While `i` is greater then `array.length`?  This is likely to be `false` and when it's not, it will cause an `IndexOutOfBoundsException`...

You're also fill the array with the same number...

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I would note is that you are filling the `Array` with the *same random number*. If you want to fill the array with different numbers you should do:

```
public void fillArray(){
    for(int i= 0; i > array.length ; i++){
        int arrayNumber = randomNumber.nextInt(100)+1;
        array[i] = arrayNumber;
        output.setText(Integer.toString(arrayNumber));
    }
}
```

In Java 8 you can make this slightly simpler:

```
array = new Random().ints(0, 100 + 1).limit(size).toArray();
textArea.setText(IntStream.of(array).
        mapToObj(Integer::toString).
        collect(Collectors.joining("\n")));
```

i.e. you first create the `int[]` by streaming the required number of random numbers. The you fill the `TextArea` by joining the array on a delimiter. I have used `\n` - a line break - but you could use anything you want.